# null-valued expression error in simple powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a small powershell script that looks in a patch for all files that contain a string and then replace that string.

Im sure this worked last week so im very confused why its now not working.

```
$filePath = "C:\my\file\path*"
# Get the files from the folder and iterate using Foreach
Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
# Read the file and use replace()
    (Get-Content $_).Replace('oldString','NewString') | Set-Content $_
}
```

Im getting two errors i think, the first is:

```
 Get-Content : Access to the path 'C:\my\file\path\YYY' is denied.
```

YYY is a folder in my path and im running the script as administrator, i was running as my own user who i confirmed has full access to this path.

The second is:

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Im guessing its the $_ but im really not sure. Ive tried replacing it with different name but no luck.

Comment: Did your root path have subfolders previously, or has the first one been added in the last week? I’m going from memory so I could be wrong, but I don’t think you can ```Get-Content``` on a folder, which would maybe explain the “access denied”. Try ```Get-ChildItem … -File``` and see if that helps…

Comment: Its always had subfolders for sure

Comment: Try with appending `-File` (to only use Get-Content on Files, not Directories) and `ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` because in the C-drive you are bound to hit Access Denied errors

Comment: The Access Denied is definitely to do with folders:: ```new-item "C:\temp\aaa" -type "Directory";  get-item "c:\temp\aaa" | get-content``` gives me "get-content : Access to the path 'C:\temp\aaa' is denied.". Adding ```-File``` to ```Get-ChildItem``` should solve *that* issue at least...

Comment: Try `-LiteralPath`: `Get-Content -LiteralPath $_`

Comment: -File on get-childitem or get-content didnt work. -Literalpath on get-content didnt work either

Comment: What didn't work with ```-File```? Did you still get the Access Denied error?

Answer (score 0):

The `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` error is coming from calling the `replace` method when the result of `Get-Content $_` is null.

This can happen for a few reasons:
First, inside of your `ForEach-Object` script block, `$_` will essentially return the same value as `$_.name` which does not contain the full path to the folder or file being processed. Depending on the value of the working directory,`$PWD`, when you execute this code this could result in a bad file or folder path.

To address issues with the working directory try using `$_.FullName`. For debugging you can also write that value to the terminal to confirm where it is looking.

The issue could also be that the file has no contents. If the file is empty then the result of `Get-Content` will be $null.

Also attempting to get the content of a folder will result in an "access denied" error, after which the result of `(get-content $_)` will also be $null, resulting in the null error you received.

To summarize:
Double check your working directory.
Consider using `$_.FullName`.
Consider adding code to avoid calling `Get-Content` on folders.

Here is an example which I tested with several nested folders, some of which contained empty files and others which contained files with contents:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\testFolder -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object{
    #this write host is just for debugging, to see what the file path is
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    $fileContents = Get-Content $_.FullName
    if($fileContents -ne $null){
        $fileContents.replace('oldString','newString') | Set-Content $_.FullName
    }
}
```